# pre_match problems and won't match the value being sought

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to get a pre_match to work right to pull in the results of a value as seen below:

```
readonly="readonly" value="xxxx-xxxxxx@gigs.craigslist.org"></li>
```

I'd like to snag what's inside the value field only and go based on that and not worry about the readonly or the

Here's what I have tried to no avail:

```
preg_match("value=\"([\w-]+[0-9]+@\w*\.?craigslist.org)\"/i", $compiled_results, $matches2);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seen is that you're missing the beginning delimiter `/`. You can also use `'` to quote your regular expression and avoid escaping here and replace the part before `@` with `[\w-]+`

What about simply the following?

```
preg_match('/value="([\w-]+@\w*\.?craigslist\.org)"/i', $compiled_results, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/vI7fP4)

Depending on whether or not you are looking for that **specific** match or just wanting to match and capture everything between the quotation's of the value field, you could simply use.

```
preg_match('/value="([^"]*)"/i', $compiled_results, $match);
```

Comment: That seems to have done it! Thanks for your help. And I thought for white spaces it was +s? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Missing starting /

```
preg_match("/value=\"([\w-]+[0-9]+@\w*\.?craigslist.org)\"/i", $compiled_results, $matches2);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to catch it still.

Comment: @MrTechie: Can you provide an example value for `xxxx-xxxxxx`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
preg_match("/value=\"(\w+-\d+@\w+\.?craigslist.org)\"/i", $compiled_results, $matches2);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/83404)